# Circle Progressing Bar in XAML

Tags: xaml, user-interface, uwp

Iam trying to create a circle progressing bar for my UWP app like this

[image: screenshot]

I just started coding xaml for a few day, so sure I need more pratice. But i really want to build this thing right now so badly.
What I read on the internet that, I have to create an
  like this (done that)
and then use the "Path" to make it move around the circle
but the "Path" property inside the Microsoft document is so complicated, I just cant understand how to controll the path

Comment: check here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47860726/uwp-radial-progress-bar-image-fill/47874002#47874002

Comment: You may also take a look [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/23047288/2681948) how it can be done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily use **UWP Community Toolkit** to do that, check this [RadialProgressBar](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwpcommunitytoolkit/controls/radialprogressbar) , also you can see the code here [RadialProgressBarSource](https://github.com/Microsoft/UWPCommunityToolkit/tree/master/Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls/RadialProgressBar)

after add UWP Comminity Toolkit in your project use it in xaml like below

```
     <controls:RadialProgressBar x:Name="RadialProgressBarControl"
           Value="70"
           Minimum="0"
           Maximum="180"
           Thickness="4"
           Outline="Gray"
           Foreground="Red">
     </controls:RadialProgressBar>
```

[image: Radial Progress Bar Control]

Comment: but why isnt it found on Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls ?

Comment: this error show up RadialProgressBar doesnt exist in the namespace Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

Comment: first find it from nuget with search this : **Microsoft.Toolkit.UWP** download and install it then add this line in your xaml namespace `xmlns:controls="using:Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls"`

Comment: you have facebook or something, If we could talk that could be lot easier

Comment: i cant use this ? wth

Comment: I add the nuget even it show up in the toolbox, but this thing keep hang it up.         public global::Windows.UI.Xaml.Markup.IXamlType GetXamlType(string fullName)
        {
            if(_provider == null)
            {
                _provider = new global::CircleProgessing.CircleProgessing_XamlTypeInfo.XamlTypeInfoProvider();
            }
            return _provider.GetXamlTypeByName(fullName);
        }

Comment: dear @StrypperVandelJason ensure you have this three item in your references : 1) Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp 2) Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Animation 3)Microsoft.Toolkit.Uwp.UI.Controls

Comment: Alright it's working fine now 
Btw parsa is there any group of people develop UWP 
Iam really struggle when doing this alone

Comment: what do you mean ?

Comment: How can I make the outline move

Comment: use a timer an increase the value of radialprogressbar

Comment: I dont know how to do that @@. Can you show me ? or give me a code example would be nice

Comment: suppose your radialprogressbar name is rpb , use a `while(rpb.Value < 100) { rpb.Value++; await task delay(5); }` i use a short delay in order to simulate progress bar move with this line `await task delay(5);`

Comment: I got the error at the await task delay(5); . Do i need my method to be async or something or using thread ??

Comment: yeah, when you use await keyword you must use it in async method

Comment: are you on the desktop right now ? pls teamview for me :(( I cant create the code

Comment: not available for me right now, what is your error ?

Comment: Task doesnt exist in the current content

Comment: add this name space top of your class `using System.Threading.Tasks;`

Comment: And the task doesnt contain a definition for delay

Comment: ensure you type Task not task

Comment: here is my code : 
        private async void RadialProgressBarControl_ValueChanged(object sender, RangeBaseValueChangedEventArgs e)
        {
            while(RadialProgressBarControl.Value < 100)
            {
                RadialProgressBarControl.Value++;
                await Task.delay(5);
            }
        }

Comment: Alright and now how to trigger it ? I start app but it just stay 0

Comment: in some action change value to from 0 to 1 then this event trigged

Comment: Dont know how to do that either :)) Dude I know you really mad at me now :( but em really suck at coding

Comment: How can we add add a textblock in the center of it ?

Comment: use a grid element, fill the width of it like `<Grid>
                <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                    <RowDefinition></RowDefinition>
                </Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                    <ColumnDefinition></ColumnDefinition>
                </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                <UWPtoolkit:RadialProgressBar Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" HorizontalAlignment="Center"/>
                <TextBlock  VerticalAlignment="Center" HorizontalAlignment="Center" Text="YourText"></TextBlock>
            </Grid>`

Answer (score 0):

I tried finding a library for Xamarin Forms but couldn't find any which had support for both Android as well as iOS. Moreover, there isn't much of choice to choose from different types of progress indicators. I ended up building up my own custom radial progress indicator widget in Xamarin Forms using SkiaSharp which supported both Android & iOS.

Tutorial Link: https://medium.com/@kpshinde25/custom-radial-progress-indicator-in-xamarin-forms-c7ed81840c1e

You can modify the code to have a circle, multi-circle indicators etc as per your requirement.